# C++ error cleanup

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management

If I have a function I call when there is an error in my app, and I call `ExitProcess` in that function to exit. Do I need to find a way to have it call things like `WSACleanup()` and `ReleaseMutex` and `RemoveFontMemResourceEx`, and free other manually allocated variables?

I believe the system does this automatically when my application exits, but is there a reason i'd want to call these cleanup functions anyways?
And if I don't, do I need to even call them right before my application exits?

Comment: your question is not tagged correctly. I don't see a direct relationship to C and on the other hand you seem to heavily rely on the specificities of a particular OS. Please correct that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title is "C++ error cleanup question", and there is a [c++] tag on it, so... **Why aren't your resources (memory, network connections, mutexes, critical sections, etc.) handled by [RAII](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)?**

If you have an error, then throw an exception, handle it higher on the stack if you can handle it, and let it crash the app if you can't (or catch it in the main, and exit the main gracefully with an error code).

Upon stack unwinding, all your RAII-protected resources will be cleaned away (so you won't have any resource leak).

The advantage of the solution is:

1. You don't have to deal with resources yourself, as RAII does it automatically.
2. If one day  you believe you can handle an error, just catch the exception at the point you can handle it, and recover.

Answer (score 3):

Most (all?) modern operating systems release most resources when a process exits, so most of the time it's safe to just exit. But there are reasons to release them explicitly.

First, if you use resource leakage detection tools (like valgrind for memory leaks for example), it's gonna give you false positives.

Second, if your code gets refactored in the future, you may forget about some resources and cause leakage.

So I think it's always a good idea to release resources as soon as you're done with them.

Comment: releasing resources is necessary for proper memory leakage testing but you don't really need it for an error handling exit..

Comment: Closing network connections is a good idea to do them explicity. It tells the other side that the connection is closed and thus able to reuse port numbers

Comment: yi_H: Agreed, but my other point still stands. Ed Heal: Yes, Unix semaphores are another example of resources that are not properly handled by the system.

Comment: @Ed Heal: the OS will do that if you don't explicitly close it.

Answer (score 1):

The `atexit` function might be useful - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atexit/

Comment: +1 for suggesting a function registered with `atexit` is exactly what I was going to suggest.

Comment: ... only that won't work if you're using `ExitProcess`, because the termination will bypass the CRT wiring. It would make sense, though, if the OP replaced the use of `ExitProcess` with the more appropriate `exit`, for that exact reason.